# In Angular 14, with the HttpClient library, how do I properly have my model's Date field populated from my API?

Tags: angular, date, model, httpclient, angular14

I'm using Angular 14.  I have a model with a Date field

```
export class MyObject {
    id!: number;
    myDate! : Date;
    ...
}
```

I do searches for the model using the HttpClient library

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
   ...
    return this.http.post<MyObject[]>(`${this.entitiesUrl}search`, searchObj)
```

The JSON returned from the API contains fields like this

```
[
    {
        ...
        "myDate": "2022-02-14",
        ...
    }
]
```

However, when I inspect my "MyObject" models, their "myDate" fields aren't Dates, they are strings.  How do I get Angular or the HttpClient library to convert this field to properly be a Date?

Comment: What is the type of the property in the api? If it is string you should convert it to date in TS,  Besides, what do you mean `their "myDate" fields aren't Dates, they are strings.` ?

Comment: What are you talking about?  I have declared the field thusly -- "myDate! : Date;", so that's a proper Date declaration, no?  But when I analyze the MyObject.myDate field afeter the API call, the type of the field is a string.

Comment: `"myDate": "2022-02-14"`  does not look like a date type. you should convert the myDate field to date in type script like so: `const str = '2024-07-21';

const date = new Date(str);`

Comment: There is no automatic conversion to date. You have to do it yourself.

Comment: @ayala, is there any way I can format the result from my API so that this conversion happens automatically?  If not, where am I putting the code you suggested?  Might be easier if you phrase it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the Angular HttpClient doesn't convert the response to an actual instance of your class by default. That is why the dates appear to be strings on your end - because they actually are. You are just getting the results of a JSON deserialization.

One way around this is to pipe(map) the response and either create a new instance of your class with the response or convert the date fields on the response to actual date types.

```
this.http.post<MyObject[]>(`${this.entitiesUrl}search`, searchObj).pipe(map((response) => {
  response.foreach((ele) => {
    ele.myDate = new Date(ele.myDate);
  })
}))
```

Comment: I think you mean "forEach" instead of "foreach."  But aside from that, anyway this logic can be placed in the constructor of my model?

Comment: I dont think that the constructor is a nice place, what if another place will initialize this MyObject?  The right place is in the pipe-map of the api call response, like @cbc wrote in the answer.

Comment: I disagree.  If you have numerous API calls that all return the same object and you need a data transformation applied to all of them, you have to duplicate that code across all API calls.  In most programming paradigms, this is done in object initialization to avoid code duplication.